# How to exit the terminal window in a program in java?

Tags: java

I have created a game in java and use the ' System.exit(0); ' to exit the program. However it only stops the program execution and minimizes the terminal window. I don't want that to happen and instead want to completely exit the program and close the terminal window.

Please tell me if it is possible and if possible then how?

Comment: Have you tried `System.exit()`

Comment: It will depend on OS, user permissions, etc. It won't be a portable solution.

Comment: How do you launch your game and how is the terminal window opened? Do you open it manually (e. g. by pressing Ctrl+R and typing cmd) or does your game launch it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM process.exe");
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will help as this is Windows-specific

Comment: Ya, This is windows specific. Have to execute separate command for Linux and Windows. We can identify os by System.getProperty("os.name")

Comment: And it strongly depends on how the game was launched :/